# Getting Android Emulator to work with SmartFace

Tags: android, android-emulator, smartface.io

I am running SmartFace version 4.5, and am trying to run an app on Android Emulator. SmartFace recognizes the emulated device, and the Emulator App is installed, but I get the message "Unfortunately, Smartface emulator stopped". Other apps on the emulated device also display a similar message "Unfortunately, Browser stopped".

What can I do? I have tried behind a proxy, without a proxy, tried different platforms and activated VM acceleration (otherwise the emulator doesnt't work).

Is there a memory problem? Do I have to mount a virtual SD card?

My settings for emulated device:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should mount sdcard too, at least for using Smartface Emulator. For installing resources of your project into emulator application Smartface uses sdcard of your device.

I also suggest that have an Arm cpu for emulated device maybe that matters also but not sure.

Comment: When you say "mount SD card", do you mean to use the "File" option, or can I just go ahead and set a reasonable "Size"? How big should that be then?